# Android's Firestore's snapshot listener on query takes too long (1 min) to update from the network when returning from being in the background

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm seeing terrible update frequency when resuming the app after it had been in the background for a while. If I kill and re-launch the app from scratch it'll usually query the most recent data fine. Similarly, when I first start listening for snapshots it works as expected, receiving data as soon as the firestore data is updated.

**It is only after the app has been in the background for too long (say 1-2 hours) and I reopen it that I see the query return cached data but not receive an update from the network for 30-90 seconds.**

Here's my query:

```
firestore.collection(GAMES_COLLECTION)
          .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("time_utc", start)
          .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("time_utc", end)
          .orderBy("time_utc")
          .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            val games = snapshot.map { doc -> doc.toObject(GameEntity::class.java) }
          }
```

The "Game" document is not too complex either (19 primitive fields and 1 array field that has 0-3 elements)

The "time_utc" field is an int that has one of the automatic indexes enabled (ascending/descending)

I've tried subscribing in a couple of different ways to see if that's the problem but I really doubt that's the problem given that it's not a problem of the subscription being lost or something, if I stay for long enough (1 minute) I'll eventually get an update. I'm subscribing on jetpack's ViewModel's init and unsubscribing in onCleared() (i.e. fragment's onCreate/ onDestroy).

I also tried having a single "global" subscription (started in the Application class' onCreate()) in case it was a "cold start" issue but that doesn't work either.

Also tried using .get().addOnSuccessListener() on that same query through a manual refresh when I know the data is stale and I'm not getting network updates but it immediately returns the same cached data.

Offline persistence is enabled, I have not setup any caching limits.

Using firestore 21.5.0

**EDIT: Found more folks dealing with the same exact problem but in the flutter SDK:**
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4305
[My Flutter app with Firestore experiences very slow queries when it is resumed from the background on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434654/my-flutter-app-with-firestore-experiences-very-slow-queries-when-it-is-resumed-f#comment116410663_63434654)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `firestore` work internally, what happen with the connection in few hours in background, maybe there are connectivity manager or other constructs and the connection may terminated, but I think that for sure **you shouldn't keep `snapshotListener` in the background** for hours/days (when you click `home` button `viewmodel's` `onClear()` not called).

I think it's wrong way to add `snapshotListener` in `viewmodel's` `init` block and unsubscribe in `onClear`, you should subscribe/unsubscribe at least at `onStart()`/`onStop()`.

This way you subscribing again in `onStart()` and the initial problem with delay disappear, and also you don't leak resources(connection) when the app in background.

Comment: I'll have to test this out, but wouldn't onClear() get called when the fragment is detached? E.g. when navigating between fragments in a bottom navigation view.

Comment: When you navigate between fragments via `replace()` method, `onClear` is called(if it not a shared view model that attached to activity), but you said "It is only after the app has been in the background for too long" so I guess the app is not terminated and you clicked home button.

Comment: Sorry it was a bit misleading. You're right that going home won't clear it, but after returning to the foreground and even navigating between tabs (that I verified do trigger onCleared and recreation of the VM) it'll take up to a minute to callback with network data.
In fact, every single screen (bottom tab) that is using a firestore snapshot will be blank until that minute passes and all of a sudden all data in all screens will load.

Comment: I suspect it has more to do the with the retry backoff strategy that firestore uses for the entire instance (not just a single query/snapshot). It seems to go into a bad state and no new snapshots will come in until this retry timer (of 60s) expires and all of a sudden ALL snapshots start working again

Comment: The snapshot have delay with 1 minute and even not returns old data when attached listener? `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("time_utc", start).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("time_utc", end)` you sure don't have here issue with your time interval, that may contain no items that match the query, and match the query only after 1 min?

Comment: Is does return cached data immediately, but "fresh" (i.e. network) data doesn't show up until after a minute even though new data has been in the backend for 30-60minutes before opening the app again. 
It's surely not an issue with the query - the documents returned by that query are the exact same during the whole day, only a few fields of the documents change every minute. I've also tried with a clean project with only 1 document (no where clause) that contains a "now" field with the current timestamp. I see the same behavior.

Comment: Looks like other people have this issue with the Flutter SDK which leads me to believe that it's on the SDK or server side.
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4305
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434654/my-flutter-app-with-firestore-experiences-very-slow-queries-when-it-is-resumed-f#comment116410663_63434654